# Login form displayed even if user already connected

Tags: python, django

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
)
```

**login.html**

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

As you can see, my code is very basic. I'm using the automatic Django view for the login. Basically if a user goes on the page accounts/login, the form is displayed and when submitted, Django does all the work itself.

Everything works, except that if a user already logged in goes on the page, the form will still be displayed. I want that if the user is already connected and goes on the page he should be redirected on another page.

How can I perform that?

I'm working with the latest versions of Python (3.3.4) and Django (1.6.2).

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) indicate you should specify the `action` in your form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
```

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't solve the problem. The form shouldn't by displayed if the user is already connected.